# With ModelSim, how to obtain all signals' simulation data before adding signals to waveform window?

Tags: vhdl, verilog, modelsim, intel-fpga

Background : ModelSim v10.4d installed with quartus v16.0

I was a Cadence Incisive user, now have to pass to mentor ModelSim, but with ModelSim I can't find a way to get all signals' data before adding them to the waveform window.

For example,

In an .do(tcl) ModelSim simmulation script, a typical flow could be:

```
1,vcom : compile all sources files and testbench
2,vsim : load testbench for simulation
3,view structure/signals/wave : open some windows
4,add wave : add signals to waveform window
5,run xx us : run simulation for a certain time
```

with this flow, I have to re-do step 5 each time adding a signal to waveform window, or it will show me "NO DATA" for that newly added signal.

So I wonder if it's possible that we skip step 4, do step 5 just once to obtain all signals' simulation data, then we choose signals to send to waveform window, and we have every signal's data without re-doing the "run".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command you need is `log`. The reference manual says:

> This command creates a wave log format (WLF) file containing simulation data for all HDL objects whose names match the provided specifications.

Try this flow, you can go to step 6 before the end of step 5 :

1- `vcom *.vhd`           : compile all sources files and testbench
2- `vsim work.my_tb`           : load testbench for simulation
3- view structure/signals/wave : open some windows
4- `log * -r`           : tell modelsim to record everything
5- `run xx us`           : run simulation for a certain time
6- add signals to waveform window

Using the `log * -r` will slow the simulation down and fill your disk up. So, you perhaps would wish to target a specific part of your design rather than using `*` or perhaps would wish to restrict the depth using the `-depth` option. Full details can be found in the Modelsim reference manual, available via the `Help` menu.

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactly what I want. Actually I don't have a very big project, so I didn't feel that `log * -r` slowed down the simulation.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add every signal in the design, just do something like:

```
add wave -recursive -depth 10 *
```

This will add every signal up to 10 levels of hierarchy deep. Note that the signal logging only applies to simulation run after the `add` command.

In a large design, logging every signal will cause the simulation to slow down. By picking and choosing which signals you are actually interested in *before* running the simulation, you will get the shortest simulation run time.

You can quickly navigate the design using the 'sim' panel, then right-click an object in the 'Objects' panel to add to wave. Here you can also <kbd>Add to > Wave > Signals in region</kbd>, or in the 'sim' panel you can <kbd>Add to > Wave > Signals in region and below</kbd>.

Comment: the simulation slows down because all the selected signals are recorded to a file. This file IO is of course much slower then the simple operations.captured.

Comment: This isn't true if the object window doesn't show the signals, so technically the sim data isn't 'obtained' yet, to use the OPs words.